# NSDateFormatter in Swift on Linux

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, foundation

I have a code:

```
import Foundation

let date = NSDate()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter();
formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

print(formatter.stringFromDate(date))
```

In Mac all fine works, I saw just current time in my timezone in format HH:mm, but on Linux dateFormat not working, I see "Jan 3, 2016, 10:56:21 PM" this is time in UTC!

Comment: What happens if you remove `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` ?

Comment: If I remove `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` a function `formatter.stringFromDate(date)` return is empty String on Linux.

Comment: It seems the bug has been already reported: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-208

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find bug tracker of Apple...

Comment: Result: "11:47:43 PM"

Comment: I am actually seeing the same thing with the dev branch of swift 3.0.  When I try and use `NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate)` the compiler always tells me that NSDate does not have a member timeIntervalSinceDate.

Comment: @AgnosticDev Swift 3.0 is undergoing "the grand renaming" whereby which the goals of https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/ are being applied to the APIs.  `NSDate` will become `Date` and superfluous verbiage in method calls will be dropped.  In your example it would be `Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate)`.